# Input display logic in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, logic

I can't seem to find the logic to run these functions as I want to. My data is loaded from an excel file and I have an Update Shop option that runs these functions below.

My problem is that I don't want `details()` function to show the input if the IP Address is not valid. Currently even if the input is wrong it still updates the details function.

```
#show details
def details():
    os.system('cls')
    ip = str(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=1).value)      #logic at this line
    name = str(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=2).value)
    address = str(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=3).value)
    phone = str(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=4).value)
    s_type = str(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=5).value)
    supplier = str(ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=6).value)
    print('    Updating shop:')
    print('\n-----------> ' + str(shop) + ' <-----------')
    print(' IP Address: ' + ip)
    print(' Full Name: ' + name)
    print(' Address: ' + address)
    print(' Phone: ' + phone)
    print(' Shop category: ' + s_type)
    print(' Supplier: ' + supplier)
    print('------------------------------')
details()

#input with IP Address validation
def ipEntered():
    while True:
        try:
            ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=1).value = input('\nEnter new IP Address: ')   #logic at this line
            val = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=1).value
            return ipaddress.ip_address(val)
        except ValueError:
            print("\nInvalid IP Address!!!")
            time.sleep(1.15)
            os.system('cls')
            details()
ipEntered()
```

Comment: what is for you `ip not valid`?

Comment: When `ValueError` occurs, `details()` function prints input from this line `ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=1).value = input('\nEnter new IP Address: ')`. I don't want to. I want the print from `details()` function to remain unchanged.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, can you expand on it?

Comment: [Short video](https://imgur.com/a/xs4s1J5) I want to use `details()` function just to print the information about the shop. IP Address (this line `print(' IP Address: ' + ip)` should remain unchanged when the `ValueError` occurs.